# How to change SFX ZIP file compatibility mode?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, zip, compatibility

Hi i'm trying to install Driver sanfransisco on my windows 8.1 pc. After installing the game i need to install update(It is a SFX ZIP file). but when i run update setup there is an error "Cannot run in ui mode...." . I tryied to change compatibility mode by right click-> compatibility. but i can't find compatibility tab. How to change compatibility mode to windows 7 of this SFX ZIP file?

Comment: rename the exe, don't use setup.exe or update.exe

Comment: If it is a simple self-extracting zip you could try downloading 7-zip (http://www.7-zip.org/) then right-click and choose **Open Archive** and copy the files manually

Comment: @magicandre1981  Cannot rename it. No rename option